# JavaScript function on post back

Tags: javascript

I am maintaining some code someone has created and it uses a few JavaScript functions to make some div's have rounded corners - however, on a post back the corners seem to dissappear. The event for the function is below:

```
curvyCorners.addEvent(window, 'load', initCorners);
```

I'm assuming this is the problem - what event would fire for postbacks too?

Comment: `'load'` should fire for postbacks, depends on browsers. `pageShow` should always fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it manually:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    curvyCorners.initCorners();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to workaround this issue is to set **display: none** to those divs and in **initCorners** show the divs by setting **display: block** or something else

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the [`'pageshow'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event) event instead.

[W3C pageShow reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#event-pageshow)

`window.addEventListener('pageshow', initCorners, false)`

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sYjCd/2/).

However mootools doesn't recognise `'pageshow'` (Oh those leaky DOM abstractions.)